# How to make the react-day-picker wide to fill all the screen in a web app mobile version

Tags: css, react-day-picker

The problem is I can't find an appropriate way with CSS styling to make the react-day-picker wide enought to fill out all a mobile display.

I've tried to customize the css file provided by react-day-picker and a lot of styles were applied but all of them weren't successfull.

```
    .DayPicker {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-between;
        font-size: 2.5rem;
        margin: 0;
        margin-top: 2rem;
    }

    .DayPicker-wrapper {
        position: relative;
        flex-direction: row;
        user-select: none;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .DayPicker-Months {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .DayPicker-Month {
        display: table;
        margin: 0;
        margin-top: auto;
        border-spacing: 0;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        user-select: none;
    }

    .DayPicker-NavBar {
        position: relative;
    }

    .DayPicker-NavButton {
        position: absolute;
        top: 1.4rem;
        margin-top: 2px;
        width: 1.25em;
        height: 1.25em;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: 60%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        color: #8B9898;
        cursor: pointer;
        outline: none;
    }

    .DayPicker-NavButton:hover {
        opacity: 0.8;
    }

    .DayPicker-NavButton--prev {
        left: 10px;
    }

    .DayPicker-NavButton--next {
        right: 10px;
    }

    .DayPicker-NavButton--interactionDisabled {
        display: none;
    }

    .DayPicker-Caption {
        display: table-caption;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
        padding: 0.5em 0.5em;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .DayPicker-Weekdays {
        display: table-header-group;
        margin-top: 1em;
    }

    .DayPicker-WeekdaysRow {
        display: none;
    }

    .DayPicker-Weekday {
        display: table-cell;
        padding: 0.5em;
        color: #8B9898;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 0.875em;
    }


    .DayPicker-Body {
        display: table-row-group;
    }

    .DayPicker-Week {
    }

    .DayPicker-Day {
        display: table-cell;
        padding: 0.8em;
        border: 1px solid #d0d4d9;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align: center;
        cursor: pointer;
        width: 8.9vw;
    }
```

I want to make the calendar wide enought to fill all a mobile screen in my web-app (mobile version).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how but I did it. Here is the solution:

```
.DayPicker {
    flex-direction: row;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.DayPicker-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    flex-direction: row;
    user-select: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.DayPicker-Months {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.DayPicker-Month {
    display: table;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: auto;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    user-select: none;
}

.DayPicker-NavBar {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.DayPicker-NavButton {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.4rem;
    margin-top: 2px;
    width: 1.25em;
    height: 1.25em;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 60%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: #8B9898;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
}

.DayPicker-NavButton:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.DayPicker-NavButton--prev {
    left: 10px;
    background-image: url('../../images/navLeft.png');
}

.DayPicker-NavButton--next {
    right: 10px;
    background-image: url('../../images/navRight.png');}

.DayPicker-NavButton--interactionDisabled {
    display: none;
}

.DayPicker-Caption {
    display: table-caption;
    border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
    padding: 0.5em 0.5em;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
}

.DayPicker-Caption > div {
    font-family: "Open Sans", monospace;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.DayPicker-WeekdaysRow {
    display: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/*.DayPicker-Body {
    display: table-row-group;
}*/

.DayPicker-Week {
    display: table-row;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.DayPicker-Day {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 0.8em;
    border: 1px solid #d0d4d9;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 6rem;
    margin: 0;
}


.DayPicker-TodayButton {
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    color: #4A90E2;
    font-size: 0.875em;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: If anyone else is curious about this, this solution works because of the `.DayPicker` and `.DayPicker-Months` classes. Copying only those two would work fine.